Regarding Viem library. When to use sendTransaction, and when to use writeContract?
I'm building a UI, a simple send form.
The form can send native token, and erc20 (eg, usdt)
using the Viem library, while it doesn't specifically say, but it seems like:
sendTransaction only works for native token? while writeContract, works for erc20, I just want to confirm my hunch from trial and error.
It's quite confusing that the docs dont mention this.
